# Make json data descriptive in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have json data in my sql table, I need to make these descriptive with the procedure in sql.
sample introduction:

```
[{"Name":"Adam Smith","OldValue":true,"NewValue":false},
 {"Name":"John Volta","OldValue":"USA","NewValue":"France"},
{"Name":"Eva Camblye","OldValue":160,"NewValue":165}]
```

sample output:

```
Adam Smit old result : true - new result: false , 
John Volta  old result:USA - new result: France ,
Eva Camblye  old result:160 - new result: 165
```

I do not have information about the size and content of the data. The information may change, but the tags (name, oldvalue, newvalue) will not change.
how can i automate them.

note: json data is stored in nvarchar
edit 2 : Information not on separate lines.it looks like this : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a3d6522b6b9e8c9044250d380b2d73ad

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT CONCAT( val->>"$.Name",
               ' old result : ',
               val->>"$.OldValue",
               ' - new result: ',
               val->>"$.NewValue" ) readable
FROM data
```

---

> a single line looks like this : [{"Name":"Adam Smith","OldValue":true,"NewValue":false},{"Name":"John Volta","OldValue":"USA","NewValue":"France"},{"Name":"Eva Camblye","OldValue":160,"NewValue":165}] Information not on separate lines. – Can

```sql
SELECT CONCAT( jsontable.Name,
               ' old result : ',
               jsontable.OldValue,
               ' - new result: ',
               jsontable.NewValue ) readable
FROM data
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE ( data.val,
                        "$[*]" COLUMNS ( Name VARCHAR(255) PATH "$.Name",
                                         OldValue VARCHAR(255) PATH "$.OldValue",
                                         NewValue VARCHAR(255) PATH "$.NewValue") ) jsontable
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ba6e544d5fbc30f2686dc6e42f50f774

Comment: Information not on separate lines.it looks like this :https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=571725fe29d16eb1cfc1e07771ccc37d

Comment: thank you for your effort, but this is not working for me. json value not on separate lines.it looks like this : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=571725fe29d16eb1cfc1e07771ccc37d

Comment: @Can o_O I add a query for this choice - look carefully. PS. JSON in your fiddle is wrong - a comma between 2nd and 3rd objects is lost. PPS. Excess spaces and linebreaks deos not affect the output - they're ignored in JSON.